# Check if any field of struct is nil

Tags: go

If there any clean way to check if any field value of `struct` is `nil`?

Suppose i have

```
type test_struct struct {
    Name    string `json:"name" binding:"required"`
    Email   string `json:"email" binding:"required"`
    Message string `json:"message" binding:"required"`
}
```

And with [`Gin`](https://github.com/gin-gonic/gin) i am filling the `struct` with values as

```
var temp test_struct
c.Bind(&temp)
```

And everything works fine, but i want to check if any of `temp.Name`, `temp.Email`, `temp.Message` is `nil`, sure we can check it by simply comparing each field with `nil`: `if temp.Name == nil` and so on, but i am looking for a cleaner version of that, is there any?

**UPD**: Due to a lack of knowledge in `Go` language i didn't know that the `Bind` function of `gin` package return an error if we pass a strucure with `binding:"required"` fields. Thanks to @matt.s i get it. So the answer would be to check the `err`:

```
var temp test_struct
err := c.Bind(&temp)
if err != nil {
    // Do my stuff(some of fields are not set)
}
```

Comment: Strings can't be nil in go.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should first check that Bind doesn't return an error. If it doesn't then all fields will be set to their appropriate values or initialized to zero values if not. This means that the strings are guaranteed to not be nil (though they will be set to `""` if they did not have a value).